# How to get data from POST-form with spark java?

Tags: spark-java

I'm pretty new with all these things but hope that you guys can help me understand how does it work. I got a form with field . How do i get data from client back? Was looking for some information but couldnt find.

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MemberId</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txt_memberid" class="control-label">MemberId</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="txt_memberid" name="txt_memberid" placeholder="MemberId" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txt_username" class="control-label">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="txt_username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txt_password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="txt_password" name="txt_password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="" />
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input id="btn_login" name="btn_login" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" />
                <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

```
    get("/login", (request, response) -> {
        ConsoleLog.consoleLog(log, request);
        HashMap model = new HashMap();
        model.put("content", new VelocityTemplateEngine().render(new ModelAndView(new HashMap(),"templates/form_login.vtl")));
        return new ModelAndView(model, "templates/base.vtl");
    }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());

    post("/login", (request, response) -> {
        ConsoleLog.consoleLog(log, request);
        Integer memberId = -1;
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        try {
            username = request.queryParams("txt_username");
            password = request.queryParams("txt_password");
            memberId = new Integer(request.queryParams("txt_memberid"));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        log.info("MemberId="+memberId+" UserName="+username+" Password="+password);
        if (new MemberDAO().isAuth(new Auth(username,password,memberId))) {
            request.session(true);
            request.session().attribute("txt_memberid", memberId);
            request.session().attribute("txt_username", username);
        }
        return "process";
    });
```

If I send form (method=get) - all works fine request.queryParams(XXXX)
If I send form (method=post) - in request.queryParams - nothing

Maybe anyone know what I should do in POST request?

Answer (score 5):

There could be a number of things wrong. There could be an error in the Java code, HTML markup or anything else. Without knowing any other information, your best bet is to try a **trial and error methodology** to debug what's going wrong.

However, before trying that, the first thing you could do is to print out exactly what the `post` of the form is sending you:

```
post("/login", (request, response) -> {
    System.out.println(request.body());
    ...
```

**If it prints out nothing**, then the client is sending you nothing, so therefore the problem is in the view.

**If it prints out a string**, for example `txt_username=john&txt_password=pass`, then the client *is* sending you data so all you really need to do is extract the data from it using the [request object's methods provided by Spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#request). Therefore, to debug, use the trial and error methodology as mentioned:

```
post("/login", (request, response) -> {
    System.out.println(request.contentType()); // What type of data am I sending?
    System.out.println(request.params()); // What are the params sent?
    System.out.println(request.raw()); // What's the raw data sent?
    // etc ...
```